# Long colored line in textbox

Tags: matlab, colors, textbox, matlab-figure, figure

I want to indicate the meaning of different text colors in my plot in a textbox.

Here a sample code:

```
figure;
bar([1,2,3])
ylim([0 5]); text(1,2,'{\color{blue} apples} {\color{red} pears}');
annotation('textbox',[.2 .6 .3 .3],'String',{'yes','no'},'FitBoxToText','on' );
```

All I'm looking for is an adequate symbol such as a long bold line or a square to use it as a color marker in my textbox in front of 'yes' and 'no'. Similar to the colored lines in a legend. How do I implement this in a MATLAB textbox?

**Note:** None of the special characters from the [***MATLAB webpage***](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/greek-letters-and-special-characters-in-graph-text.html) seems to be of use for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided some alternatives but to me the bullet seems appropriate among the special characters listed in the [*link*](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/greek-letters-and-special-characters-in-graph-text.html) you mentioned. Check the result below:

```
figure;
bar([1,2,3])
ylim([0 5]); text(1,2,'{\color{blue} apples} {\color{red} pears}');
annotation('textbox',[0.2 0.6 0.3 0.3],'String',{['{\color{blue}','\bullet','} yes'],...
    ['{\color{red}','\bullet','} no']},'FitBoxToText','on');
```

which gives:

[image: output1]

---

If you're a fan of unicodes, you have more freedom. You can insert any of hyphen (-), em dash (—), square (■), bullet (•) and the list goes on.

`char(8212)` gives em dash, `char(9632)` gives square, and `char(8226)` gives bullet. Use whichever you want.

```
figure;
bar([1,2,3])
ylim([0 5]); text(1,2,'{\color{blue} apples} {\color{red} pears}');
annotation('textbox',[0.2 0.6 0.3 0.3],'String',{['{\color{blue}',char(8212),'} yes'],...
    ['{\color{red}',char(9632),'} no']},'FitBoxToText','on');
```

which gives:

[image: output2]

---

or you can manipulate `legend` into producing the required result as shown below:

```
figure;
plot(NaN,NaN,'b',NaN,NaN,'r'); hold on;    %The trick
bar([1,2,3])
ylim([0 5]); text(1,2,'{\color{blue} apples} {\color{red} pears}');
legend({'yes','no'},'Location','northwest');
```

which gives:

[image: output3]

Comment: Great, this was very helpful!
If anyone reads this and would like to do it on a single line: 

`annotation('textbox',[0.2 0.6 0.3 0.3],'String',{['{\color{blue}',char(9632),'} yes'],['{\color{red}',char(9632),'} no']},'FitBoxToText','on');`

Comment: @Surstroemmingpirat Good point. Infact this seems more reasonable. I have added your suggestion into the original answer. Thanks